# Backgroundless and Windowless OpenGL application

Tags: linux, opengl

Have you used or seen cairo dock in linux? I've read in wikipedia that's it was written in C. I'm just curious how did they make a windowless, widget-like app which use OpenGl. Is it possible to make an OpenGl application which is windowless and has no background(or transparent background).  Did they made it with C from scratch? or Did they used any other tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by "windowless". A window is the (rectangular) region on screen to which you can draw with drawing operations. From your question however I have the impression, that you're actually asking about creating a window without **decorations** (i.e. title bar, etc.).

In Linux, or more precisely X11, the appearance of a window is controlled by two things: The *Extended Window Manager Hints (EMWH)* for a window under control of the window manager; the window manager is the actual program responsible for drawing the decorations and borders. And the *Redirection Override* flag, which controls, if a window actually gets to be under the control of a window manager. If you're asking about "backgroundless", then I presume you mean, transparent. First have a look at this video I made: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iHZfH1Qhonk Is this what you're after? Then what you actually want is a window with an *Alpha channel* in its framebuffer config (X11 XRender FBConfig), together with a compositing manager (which can, but isn't required to be a part of the window manager). The sourcecode for this program can be found at https://github.com/datenwolf/codesamples/tree/master/samples/OpenGL/x11argb_opengl_glsl

Or are you actually asking about a OpenGL context to which you can render a picture, but without it appearing on screen? That would then be an off-screen context and there are two ways for implementing this with X11:

- Using a windowless PBuffer X11 drawable for the context
- Using a hidden window together with a OpenGL Framebuffer Object

Both methods have each their pros and cons.